# Why data is not ingested by vertica after i added columns in table?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, vertica

I added two columns in my table, then I start scheduler in vertica but vertica didn't receive any data through kafka. Kafka broker is okay it is producing and consuming data but vertica didn't receive it.

Note:Before any insertion of column in table, vertica is running fine.

I delete target and then I create it.

```
vkconfig target --delete --target-schema public --target-table web_hits --conf weblog.conf
vkconfig target --create --target-schema public --target-table web_hits --conf weblog.conf
```

and same I do for load-spec and microbatch command but no use.It still didn't receive any data after I launch scheduler

Comment: Did you also add the columns the relevant topic in kafka?

Look for `too few columns found` in vertica.log

Comment: Agreed. You can also try the COPY command to copy a sample of the Kafka topic into a flex table. From there you can inspect the columns that are coming in from the Kafka topic.

Comment: @ya2410 yes i  added columns in kafka side.

Comment: Should i shutdown the scheduler  to add columns then start again?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to avoid problem

1) Shutdown scheduler

2) add or remove columns in vertica sql as well as on kafka side

3) start scheduler again